# How to pivot N observations of a time series column at a time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy

I have a dataframe like this

```
    date
2018-02-28 09:00:00    78700.0
2018-02-28 10:00:00    78900.0
2018-02-28 11:00:00    78100.0
2018-02-28 12:00:00    78100.0
2018-02-28 13:00:00    77500.0
                        ...
2018-11-30 11:00:00    70000.0
2018-11-30 12:00:00    69800.0
2018-11-30 13:00:00    69800.0
2018-11-30 14:00:00    69600.0
2018-11-30 15:00:00    69400.0
```

and I want to pivot a time series variable for a certain length in each row (this case, timestep is 6, so I expect 6 columns per row). The expected result below is similar to a subset of a Toeplitz matrix.

```
date                       0        1        2        3        4        5
2018-02-28 09:00:00  78700.0  78900.0  78100.0  78100.0  77500.0  77100.0
2018-02-28 10:00:00  78900.0  78100.0  78100.0  77500.0  77100.0  77100.0
2018-02-28 11:00:00  78100.0  78100.0  77500.0  77100.0  77100.0  76300.0
2018-02-28 12:00:00  78100.0  77500.0  77100.0  77100.0  76300.0  76200.0
2018-02-28 13:00:00  77500.0  77100.0  77100.0  76300.0  76200.0  76700.0
...                      ...      ...      ...      ...      ...      ...
2018-11-29 12:00:00  72000.0  72000.0  71800.0  71500.0  71500.0  70000.0
2018-11-29 13:00:00  72000.0  71800.0  71500.0  71500.0  70000.0  70000.0
2018-11-29 14:00:00  71800.0  71500.0  71500.0  70000.0  70000.0  69800.0
2018-11-29 15:00:00  71500.0  71500.0  70000.0  70000.0  69800.0  69800.0
2018-11-30 09:00:00  71500.0  70000.0  70000.0  69800.0  69800.0  69600.0
```

I just appended splited chunks into new Dataframe to make this, but it's too slow ;(
Is there a elegant way to perform this transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way of achieving your desired output using a [Hankel matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_matrix) and some array manipulation. You can construct a Hankel matrix with the [`scipy.linalg.hankel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.hankel.html#scipy.linalg.hankel) function.

In the following I define a custom function `time_series_to_hankel()` that takes as input your pandas DataFrame, the time-series variable you want to stack in one row, and the number of time steps.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.linalg import hankel

def time_series_to_hankel(data, ts_col, n_steps):
    
    # generate hankel dataframe for the time series column
    h = hankel(data[ts_col])[:(data.shape[0] - n_steps + 1), :n_steps]
    h_df = pd.DataFrame(h, columns=['t_' + str(i) for i in range(h.shape[1])])
    
    # manipulate the original df
    temp_df = data.drop(columns=['value']).loc[:(h.shape[0] - 1)]
    
    # concat the two dataframes
    return pd.concat([temp_df, h_df], axis=1)
```

I suggest you to go run it step by step if you want to understand the rationale in all the passages.

---

Example

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.linalg import hankel

# similar to your sample dataset
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.date_range('2018-02-28 09:00:00', '2018-11-30 15:00:00', freq='H'),
    'test_var': np.random.randint(1, 10, size=6607),
    'value': np.linspace(78700, 69400, num=6607).astype(int)
})

time_series_to_hankel(df, 'value', n_steps=6)
                    date  test_var    t_0    t_1    t_2    t_3    t_4    t_5
0    2018-02-28 09:00:00         7  78700  78698  78697  78695  78694  78692
1    2018-02-28 10:00:00         9  78698  78697  78695  78694  78692  78691
2    2018-02-28 11:00:00         2  78697  78695  78694  78692  78691  78690
3    2018-02-28 12:00:00         8  78695  78694  78692  78691  78690  78688
4    2018-02-28 13:00:00         1  78694  78692  78691  78690  78688  78687
...                  ...       ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...
6597 2018-11-30 06:00:00         8  69412  69411  69409  69408  69407  69405
6598 2018-11-30 07:00:00         4  69411  69409  69408  69407  69405  69404
6599 2018-11-30 08:00:00         3  69409  69408  69407  69405  69404  69402
6600 2018-11-30 09:00:00         6  69408  69407  69405  69404  69402  69401
6601 2018-11-30 10:00:00         4  69407  69405  69404  69402  69401  69400
```